# DROP or REJECT packets from PREROUTING NAT table in iptables

Tags: iptables, nat

Goal is to allow only specific networks to access docker container services/ports running on my server.

Tried adding ACCEPT rules in to INPUT filter chain. That did not help, networks even without ACCEPT rule were still able to access docker service/port.

Tried adding ACCEPT and DROP rules in FORWARD chain, this works. But this has many disadvantages like: a. Rules getting deleted or re-positioned on docker restart b. Rules can become invalid, if docker containers are re-deployed and get different IPs at runtime

Plan is to BLOCK them before even reaching FORWARD chain.

So, added a new chain in NAT table, which redirects to DOCKER chain if traffic is from allowed network, if it is from other networks, added DNAT to a BLOCKHOLE IP. In PREROUTING, first rule is to jump to this chain.This seems to be working.

DNAT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:1234 to:0.0.0.1

But, instead of redirecting it to a BLOCKHOLE, can we somehow REJECT this traffic so that the client knows it is not allowed and hence refused.

Comment: Tried:
DNAT tcp -- 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp dpt:1234 to:<Server-IP>

And catch the same port traffic in INPUT filter and DROP/REJECT.

Even then the client gets 'Connection Timedout'.

So its same behavior even if we direct the traffic to a BLOCKHOLE.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't particularly nice, but if you DNAT the traffic from somewhere in PREROUTING to a blackhole address (pick some reserved network address like 192.0.2.1 from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_IP_addresses ) then you can reject/drop in FORWARD in the filter table. This way you only need one rule there and hopefully better avoid it being repositioned.